# Java Intersecting Specific Locations on Lines

Tags: java, intersection, rectangles

I am trying to focus on collision detection for a game that I'm creating.

collisionBox is the Rectangle of the player of the game.
All of the lines represent a specific edge of a Rectangle, or wall, that the player cannot go through.

```
leftLine = new Line2D.Float((float) wall.getMinX(), (float) wall.getMaxY() , (float) wall.getMinX(), (float) wall.getMinY());
rightLine = new Line2D.Float((float) wall.getMaxX(), (float) wall.getMaxY(), (float) wall.getMaxX(), (float) wall.getMinY());
topLine = new Line2D.Float((float) wall.getMinX(), (float) wall.getMaxY(), (float) wall.getMaxX(), (float) wall.getMaxY());
botLine = new Line2D.Float((float) wall.getMinX(), (float) wall.getMinY(), (float) wall.getMaxX(), (float) wall.getMinY());

hitLeft = leftLine.intersects(collisionBox);
hitRight = rightLine.intersects(collisionBox);
hitTop = topLine.intersects(collisionBox);
hitBottom = botLine.intersects(collisionBox);

if (hitTop) {
    return Top;
} else if(hitBottom) {
    return Bottom;
} else if(hitLeft) {
    return Left;
} else if (hitRight){
    return Right;
}
```

The bug I have is that because the top and bottom walls are evaluated first then if I hit a side(left/right) wall towards the top or the bottom, then obviously one of the first two checks will incorrectly return true instead.
Other features in my code depend on knowing exactly which side of the wall that was hit, so a more simple collisionBox.intersects(wall) would not suffice.

Though I understand the issue itself, I am stumped with any form of solution and really hope that you guys could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are drawing four lines and then checking each one independently. A solution would be to use the [2dRectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) class and simply check the X and Y coordinates of the rectangle to know what side it collided on. Doing an if statement like that would be difficult to get working.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, I'm sorry. 

consider the following adaptation that only runs if collisionBox.intersects(wall).
<code>
hitLeft = collisionBox.getMaxX() > wall.getMinX();
hitRight = collisionBox.getMinX() < wall.getMinX();
hitTop = collisionBox.getMinY() < wall.getMaxY();
hitBottom = collisionBox.getMaxY() > wall.getMinY();
</code>

the if statement would then always return Top, because it is the first evaluated and hitTop will actually always be true if there is an intersection.

Comment: Yes the problem is that you are drawing four different lines. Instead, you could have one rectangle object and check the X and Y values of that rectangle, instead of checking each line independently. That if statement is not going to work how you want it to, so you need to rethink your approach.